# Java searching an array for repeating pattern

Tags: java, arrays, design-patterns

I have a program that is searching a maze to find the best way out. As it searches it adds the next move to an array. My problem is that it keeps repeating the same three moves over and over. I need to find the best way to check that array of moves in order to force it to change move when a loop has been detected.

edit for clarity, 
http://www.logicmazes.com/theseus.html maze three is the one I'm testing. what happens is that it gets stuck moving up and down in the column it starts in.

Comment: Instead of removing the bad moves from your array, wouldn't it be better to fix your code so it doesn't generate them in the first place?

Comment: The code strives to find the minimum solution to the maze, and worked in the smaller test maze. If I can figure out how to check the last few elements for a repeating loop I can reset it, re-evaluating the decision making it uses to get stuck in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is that your "state" doesn't actually contain enough state information. In every cycle, after Theseus has moved and the Minotaur has moved twice, the state consists of the following:

- Theseus's x-coordinate.
- Theseus's y-coordinate.
- The Minotaur's x-coordinate.
- The Minotaur's y-coordinate.

You can represent these as some sort of `MazeState` object whose `equals` and `hashCode` methods make it easy to see if two instances represent the same state.

Since the Minotaur's motion follows a very rigid program, every move that Theseus makes (left/right/up/down/delay) will move from one well-defined state to another. You then need to forbid Theseus from making any moves that:

- Would cause the Minotaur's x- and y-coordinates to equal those of Theseus (since this means Theseus is dead).
- Would cause the new state to be equal to a state that you've previously been in (since this means that no progress has been made).

To do this, you can store the previous states in a `HashSet<MazeState>`.

Comment: your first bullet point has been covered, as part of theseus's move method it will pick a random move instead of the move that would cause it to be killed. the idea is that it does get caught originally, but realises that the original movement was a bad idea so changes its strategy. the second point is more annoying though as   it can be necessary to go back on itself, eg on maze 3 it has to delay in the bottom left, then backtrack towards the exit, You see?

Comment: @confusified: I disagree. It *never* has to return to a previous *state*. Theseus has to return to a previous *position* sometimes, but the *state* consists of both *his* position *and* the Minotaur's, and *that* should never repeat. Do you see what I'm saying?

Comment: I see... now what I have is a Theseus and a Minotaur class. Theseus also keeps track of the minotaurs position. I dont have an actual state object, but i have a matrix of each possible transition from the current state. 
eg
actionsFromA[A,B,D]
actionsFromB[A,B,E]

Comment: @confusified: Are you sure that you have a matrix of each possible transitions from the entire current *state*, and not just a matrix of moves from the current *position of Theseus* (which is just part of the state)? Because if you have a matrix of transitions from the entire current *state*, then that implies that you really do have some sort of state object.

Comment: Sorry, i mean i have a matrix of all possible transitions (from space to space) for each position on the board. does that make sense?

Comment: @confusified: That makes perfect sense -- and it's not enough. I'm telling you, you really need to create some sort of object that actually represents the current state, so that you can check to make sure that you never return to a state you've previously been to. (Obviously this object doesn't *have* to be its own class -- you could just use an `int[]` with four elements if you want -- but giving it its own class makes it very convenient to compare two states for equality, to store them in a set, etc.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9245/discussion-between-confusified-and-ruakh)

Answer (score 1):

You could keep track of every cell your current path has already visited, and not go to those cells again (since that would create a loop).

As far as the data structure is concerned, I see two main possibilities:

- keep an array -- or a set -- of coordinates that you've visited; or
- have a boolean array of the same dimensions as the maze, setting the visited cells to `true`.

You would need to update the structure whenever you take a step, and whenever you backtrack.

Comment: see, the problem with that is that it may actually be necessary to repeat a step. I'm automating the pathfinding of the mazes linked above. this involves trapping the minotaur before leaving the maze.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Array then you should be able to use "contains" method to check if the move is already in the array.

In order to do that you may have to modify your equals method to compare two different moves to check if they are the same.

In that case, when you identify the same move, you can ignore that and look for other moves. An example pseudo code

```
public class Move {
  int x;
  int y;

  public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o == null) return false;
    if(!(o instanceof) Move) return false;

    Move other = (Move) o;
    if(this.x != other.x) return false;
    if(this.y != other.y)   return false;

    return true;
  }
}

public class SolveMaze {
    List<Move> moves;
    ...
    public boolean isValidMove(Move move) {
        if (moves.contains(move)) return false;
        else {
            ...
                moves.add(move);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is close. Imagine it's moving in a loop of state 4 to 7 (adjoining states in my instantiation) so 4,7,4,7,4,7,4,7  etc. How would I identify this type of looping?

Comment: After you insert 4,7 you cannot have 4 again because 4 is already in the move list. If not, I'd create another Class representing something called a Leg that would be unique set of moves. You can check if the Legs are the same and not let the user follow the same leg again. For example: 4,7,6 is a leg so user cannot go through 4,7,6 again. He can go through 4,7,5,6 (which at that point will create a new Segment / leg).

Comment: I need to be able to though. 

http://www.logicmazes.com/theseus.html   maze3 is the one im on at the min.

the optimum solution is move down, down, left, pause a move, (trapping the minotaur) then run towards the exit. so as you can see this will require some of the states to be revisited.

Comment: What you have to do is probably figure out all the possible Segments and let the user not repeat the segments again. This you may have to determine ahead and populate your data structures.

Comment: I have a method that makes a random move. i need to establish that its in a loop (possibly of 3 moves) and then call that random function

Comment: You may have to put a more thought into this because a loop can be quite complex if you have a complex structure. Like maybe a 10 x 10 cube. Maybe you can allow only two repetitions of a pair of moves. Like you can only cross 4,5 twice and no more.

Comment: i think something like that could work. given the array that is being added too, 4th last and 2nd last would match, and the 3rd and last would match, at which point i could block those pairs of moves... something like that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9246/discussion-between-udaypal-aarkoti-and-confusified)